# Why is it ok to set the dilaton to its classical value in Jackiw-Teitelboim (JT) gravity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, constrained-dynamics

I am reading [arXiv:1606.01857](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01857) (Maldacena-Stanford-Yang), one of the main papers on [Jackiw-Teitelboim (JT) gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackiw%E2%80%93Teitelboim_gravity).  To derive the Schwarzian action, they use the classical solution for the dilaton, eq. (3.10).

My question is: Why is this ok?  Since this is a quantum theory, shouldn't we let the dilaton fluctuate?

I am aware that in effective field theory it is sometimes reasonable to plug in classical  solutions for some of the fields.  But I do not understanding the reasoning in the present example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dilaton in JT gravity is a Lagrange multiplier, enforcing the constraint that the spacetime is AdS<sub>2</sub>. You can then completely integrate out the dilaton, so you impose the constraint by hand and set the Lagrange multiplier to its classical value. That's also why the bulk term vanishes and you only get the boundary mode.